# UIButton in UITableView header not working?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uibutton, ibaction

I have added a UIBUtton in a UITableView header and it doesn't seem to be working. It's clickable, but when attaching a IBAction to it, it fails and does nothing.

I have read online and saw to put it in your File's Owner, but I can't do that. When I put the action in, it only shows up in my First Responder.

I have also tried to put it in a different file, but when doing do it won't let me drag it to the other file.

**FILES:**

RootViewController.h
RootViewController.m
TableViewAppDelegate.h
TableViewAppDelegate.m
DetailViewController.h
DetailViewController.m

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
    Sqlite *database;
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    UITextView *myTextField;
}

- (IBAction)addAlbum;
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "TableViewAppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

// If a user adds a photo album
- (IBAction)addAlbum {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Gallery" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -80);
[alert setTransform:myTransform];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[alert addSubview:myTextField];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[alert setTag:1];
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the flaw is in your code. Post some and we can determine that.

Comment: Just posted some... Please ask if you need to see anything else! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading  the table header view from .xib, make "File's Owner" of the .xib your ViewController subclass presenting the UITableView, and connect the desired event in the button to the desired IBAction in File's Owner.   If you're creating the button programmatically in a tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method, you must wire up the action yourself on the button using this method on the button object:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

EDIT: you should post your tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: code so we can give more specific advice.

Comment: Where are you creating the heaver view then?